# Sending different ranges of frequencies to separate channels?

Tags: mixing, effects, filter

How would I send specific ranges of frequencies to different channels like the example I made in photoshop below? Right now I'm using FL Studio 9.7

[image: Example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Send everything to all three channels, and filter out the frequencies you want per channel.

Comment: Make the first thing in the effects chain on each of the side channels a parametric EQ that gives you the frequencies you want running through those effects.

Comment: When I was laying down to sleep last night I thought of this and slapped my forehead =p Thanks guys